# Custom scrollbox in html, css and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I recently had this project handed down to me that involved writing a simple static site for a client. Normally I'm not into the website UI side, I'm more involved with the back-end of things.. anyways.

I've attached a picture that I got from the designer we hired of a custom srollbox graphic:
[image]

Since I don't know that much about CSS how would one achieve this if I have scrollable textarea in my html? Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Pure CSS3 solution: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ It even works on iOS.

Comment: @Derek - Thanks for the reply, since this article is about custom scrollbars in webkit. That means that this wont work for something like IE right?

Comment: Yes, it won't work on IE or Firefox. (Firefox said they don't want web pages to mess with the users' interface so they said no to this.) If you are looking for a cross browser solution, then you should probably look into the jQuery scroll bar plugins. They are easy to use and small in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JQuery Scroll Bar plugin:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/